# Loop stopped at 65536

Tags: php

I make a loop until 500000 and it stop at 65536, dies this php limit or system limit? Anyway to avoid it?

Btw, it's just an ordinary for loop.
`for($i=0; $i<500000; $i++){}`

real code, I care about the load, but my concern is not that one.

```
class ECStun{
    var $sp = 1;
    var $d = 5;
    var $url = 'http://example.com/';
    var $html = '';
    var $invalid = '404';

    var $data = array();

    var $db = false; // db connection
    var $dbhost = 'localhost';
    var $dbuser = 'root';
    var $dbpass = '';
    var $dbname = 'scrape';
    var $tbname = 'ecstun'; // this table will be created automatically by the script.

    var $proxies = array(
    );

    var $startat = 0;

    function init(){
        $this->initDB();
        $this->startat =  microtime(true);
        $x = rand(0, count($this->proxies)-1);
        print('start scraping using proxy : '.$this->proxies[$x]."\n");
        for($i = $this->sp; $i <= $this->d; $i++){
            $url = $this->url.'ES'.$i;
            if(!$this->isSaved($url)){ // skip is already saved to DB
                $link = curl_init();
                if(count($this->proxies) > 0){
                    curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxies[$x]);
                }
                curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17)');
                curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                $this->html = curl_exec($link);
                $code = curl_getinfo($link, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                curl_close($link);
                if($code == 200 || $code == 301){
                    $this->parse($url);
                }else{
                    /*
                    ** this block of script will make sure if IP got banned then delete the banned ip
                    ** and then check if there is another remaining IPs we can use
                    ** if no more IPs in $proxies then exit the script with information of latest ES
                    */
                    //unset($this->proxies[$x]);
                    array_splice($this->proxies, $x, 1);
                    if(count($this->proxies) > 0){
                        $this->sp = $i; // if banned then set starting point to the latest ES to try again using different ip
                        $this->init();
                    }else{
                        exit('LAST ES: ES'.$i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //$this->initDB();
    }
}

$ecs = new ECStun;
if(isset($_GET['verify_proxy'])){ // browser only
    $ecs->verifyProxy();
}else{
    $ecs->init();
}
```

Comment: How do you know it stops at 65536? Provide __real__ code

Comment: If that true... why not just... when i = 65536 so run that func again ?

Comment: Oh btw i run the script in console and i print the index to show add. Information, and it stoped at 65536 or something. Will post the code in a minutes

Comment: Which loop is the problematic one?

Comment: That seems like an incredibly unfriendly thing to do to that web site.

Comment: 65536 - probably means that your loop counter variable size is not big enough.  See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65536_(number)).

Comment: @RocketHazmat loop at init function.

Comment: Oh dear: no `sleep()` to reduce the load on the target website, directing your request traffic via proxies **and** misrepresenting your robot to look like a regular browser?

Comment: @DarielPratama If you're going to make the question unsolvable, I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: @Daedalus yes please, it's my naturally false.

Comment: @DarielPratama That doesn't make any sense; at the current point where you've edited the question to, it is unsolvable.  There is nothing wrong in the above code.  However there are multiple things wrong in your past version of it.

Comment: The new version of the question plainly will work, so it is likely to be something in the more detailed version that stops it working. OP, please roll back. ("it's my naturally false" doesn't have a particularly clear meaning in English, btw).

Comment: @halfer ok, i will. i just don't get it when i already put my real code and down still coming @.@

Comment: @DarielPratama The reason for that is likely that you are spamming connections to one website.

Comment: @Daedalus thanks for the answer, it help me so much to fix the problem.

Comment: @DarielPratama I haven't been sarcastic with you, and I'd appreciate the same.  That aside, you did ask why downvotes were still coming.  The above comment is a reply to that question; if you're not curious about it, and don't expect or want a response, then don't ask.

Comment: @Daedalus i didn't mean to be sarcastic, i am sorry. i know what is wrong with me, my code. but in my question i just want to know why it stopped at 65536, the number is familiar to us, i want to know if there is something limiting the loop in system level? that's all i want to know. once again, i appologies.

Answer (score 0):

`65535` is a magical number. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65535_%28number%29):

> 65535 occurs frequently in the field of computing because it is the
>   highest number which can be represented by an unsigned 16-bit binary
>   number.

Try this:

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);
```

It should be the `65535` to confirm your error. Try upgrading to 32 bit or more.